# Actionscript TextField doesn't display chinese characters (font is embedded)

Tags: actionscript-3, localization, textfield, embedding

So here's the situation. I have a bunch of textfields, containing some phrases, and a locale file containing translations of those phrases in several languages. I also have a textfield on the stage where I copied all the characters from the locale file (this means latin characters, plus special characters from french, spanish, and also characters in arabic, and chinese).

Now the problem: all translations appear ok, even arabic, except for chinese. For chinese, I don't see anything, only white space. If I compile the application with the chinese translations already entered in the textfields, I can see them, but as soon as I try to set them dynamically, everything disappears.

The font I'm using is Arial, Bold, and I even tried embedding the entire Chinese set of glyphs, but with no luck.

Also, I tried launching an alert window using External Interface to trace the chinese characters right before I'm setting them to the textfield, and I can see them appearing just fine in the alert box (I'm using Vizzy for watching traces, but for chinese I'm just seeing some squares).

Help me out..

Comment: But did you used that embedded font with your TextField ? Are you using ActionScript to attach the font to your TextField or just from its properties ?

Comment: so I have 2 dynamic textfield objects on stage, each using the same font and same style (Arial Bold). on one I'm adding all the characters I want to have embedded, from IDE, and on the second one I'm setting the text dynamically. the second TextField has a slight rotation applied, so I can immediately see if the characters are embedded or not. Latin characters, special characters from Latin extended and also arabic appears just fine in the rotated TextField, chinese does not. If I compile with some chinese characters in the rotated TextField, I can see them, ust not if i set them dynamically.